# using phpunit with yii - parent classes are not being recognized

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

I wrote a little test case for a model I created in Yii and when I try to run the test, it gives me: Fatal error: Class

```
'.....\ActiveRecord' not found in Commissions.php'
```

Now, my class (commissions.php) inherits the ActiveRecord class in Yii but how can I tell PHPunit where to find it?  I've tried using an include statement in Commissions.php but then it can't find the class that ActiveRecord inherits and so on.

```
<?php

include_once('Commissions.php');

class CommissionsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // Here, the idea would be to check one or two employees manually or based on the SQL query
    // Or even a previous value using the function so that when any changes are made, the value
    // remains the same while using the same arguments.
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->employee = new Commissions();
        $this->employee->employeeId = 'V1S';
        $this->employee->year = 2012;
        $this->employee->period = 1;
    }

    public function testAttributes()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('V1S', $this->employee->employeeId);
        $this->assertEquals(2012, $this->employee->year);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->employee->period);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to include the YII class loader.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  How would I specifically do that in this case?  I'm pretty new to using this framework

Comment: Me too ;) I've seen this chapter, probably it's helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.unit - Their testcases extend from a Yii base test class. I assume they take care of autoloading.

Comment: That comment would look really nice as an answer. :)

Comment: I tried using `CDbTestCase` like the doc says but still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should have at the beginning of your testcase is:

```
Yii:import('application.models.Commissions'); //or whatever your model is called
class CommissionsTest extends CDbTestCase { //Not PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```